# ¿Por qué no se captura la excepción al ingresar una fecha incorrecta?

Tags: java, excepciones

¿Por qué no se captura la excepción al ingresar una fecha incorrecta?

```
    do { 
        Aux = 0;
        System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha de nacimiento dd/mm/yyyy");
        FechaNacAdm= Leer.nextLine();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date testDate = null;
        String date = FechaNacAdm;
    try{
        testDate = sdf.parse(date);
        Aux = 1;
    } catch (Exception e){ System.err.println("invalid format");}
        if (!sdf.format(testDate).equals(date)){
        System.out.println("invalid date!!");
    }
} while (Aux == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas.
Yo he realizado estos cambios y me funciona:

```
 int Aux;
        do { 
                Aux = 0;
          System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha de nacimiento dd/mm/yyyy");
                Scanner Leer=new Scanner(System.in);
                String date =Leer.nextLine();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date testDate = null;
                
            try{
                testDate = sdf.parse(date);
                Aux = 1;
            } catch (Exception e){ 
                System.out.println("Fecha Inválida, vuelva a probar.");
            }
        } while (Aux == 0);
        System.out.println("Puede continuar.");
    }
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés leer [answer], para que la respuesta no sea considerada de baja calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Java Date tiene muchos bugs por eso java 8 incorporo librerías nuevas para el manejo de fechas. De echo en el código que muestras para una fecha “22/16/2021” que no es valida en valor, al realizar el parse lo interpretara igual como “22/01/2021” y no da error.

Por eso es mejor utilizar las nuevas librerías LocalDate que validan de mejor forma la conversión a una fecha valida, como por ejemplo:

```
Aux = 0;
System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha de nacimiento dd/mm/yyyy");
String date = Leer.nextLine();
DateTimeFormatter sdf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy");
try {
    LocalDate.parse(date, sdf);
    Aux = 1;
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("invalid format");
}

if (Aux == 0) {
    System.out.println("invalid date!!");
} else {
    System.out.println("ok date");
}
```

También hay que tener cuidado con el patrón, por que al poner "dd/MM/yyyy" tanto para el día como para el mes se exige 2 dígitos. Entonces para enero 1 del 2021 el única forma valida es "01/01/2021".
Si el patrón es "d/M/yyyy" para la misma fecha del ejemplo anterior son validas tanto "01/01/2021" como "1/1/2021"